# Error while calling a class object from another object in Angular 4 Typescript component

Tags: angular, class, object, typescript

**Introduction to the problem**
Here is my newcomp.component.ts file from Angular 4 project. I created the project using Angular CLI so it is well organized. My app name is cvfy. So the folder and file structure is as follows:
CVFY

> -e2e (folder)
>
> -node_modules (folder)
>
> -server (folder)
>
> -src (folder)
>
> --environments (folder)
>
> --assets (folder)
>
> --app (folder)
>
> ---app.component.css (file)
>
> ---app.component.html (file)
>
> ---app.component.spec.ts (file)
>
> ---app.component.ts (file)
>
> ---app.module.ts (file)
>
> **---clientlogos.ts (file)**
>
> **---imageclass.ts (file)**
>
> **---clientscomp (folder)**
>
> **----clientscomp.component.html (file)**
>
> **----clientscomp.component.spec.ts (file)**
>
> **----clientscomp.component.ts (file)**

I have mentioned the important files and folders above for my problem
I am writing my code in **clientscomp.component.ts** file and using classes **clientlogos.ts** and **imageclass.ts**

**clientscomp.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Clientlogos } from "./../clientlogos";
import { Imageclass } from "./../imageclass";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clientscomp',
  templateUrl: './clientscomp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clientscomp.component.css']
})

export class ClientscompComponent implements OnInit {

  private imageone: Imageclass[] = [
    {"_id":"1", "altClient":"Play Station", "srcClient":"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-icons-web/40/PlayStation-128.png"},
    {"_id":"2", "altClient":"Twitter", "srcClient":"https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-and-simple-part-1/128/twitter-128.png"}
  ];

  private myrows: Clientlogos[] = [
    {
      "_id":"1",
      "imagenew": this.imageone
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**clientlogos.ts**

```
import { Imageclass } from "./imageclass";

export class Clientlogos {
    "_id":string;
    "imagenew":Imageclass[];
}
```

**imageclass.ts**

```
export class Imageclass {
    "_id": string;
    "altClient": string;
    "srcClient": string;
}
```

**The error it shows on running the application is:**

```
Failed to compile.

C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/Learning/cvfy/src/app/clientscomp/clientscomp.component.ts (40,7): Type '{ "_id": string; "imagenew": Imageclass[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Clientlogos[]'.
  Type '{ "_id": string; "imagenew": Imageclass[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Clientlogos'.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"imagenew"' does not exist in type 'Clientlogos'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use Array in you class, to make it more statically typed.**

```
class Menu {
  name: string;
  categories: Array<Category>; // initialize it as applicable
}
class Category {
  name: string;
  dishes: Array<Dish>;// initialize it as applicable
}
class Dish {
  name: string;
}
```

**Component**

You can try fill this.menus which will also be strongly typed Array // make sure the code is written to compile.

```
getMenus() {
    this.globals.getMenus().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.menus = new Array<Menu>();
        Object.keys(data).forEach(name => {
          //Initialize and push items as per data structure. 
          this.menus.push(new Menu(data[name]));
        });

        console.log(this.menus);
      },
      err => { console.log(err) }
    );
  }
```

**template Arrange the following as a combination of Un-ordered and ordered list.**

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let menu of menus">
        {{ menu.name }}
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let category of menu.categories">
                {{ category.name }}
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let dish of category.dishes">
                        {{ dish.name }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```